# git from checked-out stash to branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-stash

I want 100% of stash `4aa0f82` below on my master branch

Problem is, stash apply/pop does not apply all the changes. I can resolve some conflicts, but some important stuff that I changed and saved in the stash does not appear in the conflicts (maybe because there was a commit with a detached HEAD in between).

I want 100% of the stash on my branch. it is all there when I do checkout stash@{0}. how do I move that full stashed commit on my branch?

`git log --graph --decorate --oneline stash` output:

```
*-.   6872ac5 (refs/stash) WIP on (no branch): d5da51e
|\ \
| | * 52db257 untracked files on (no branch): d5da51e
| * fb1c947 index on (no branch): d5da51e
|/
*   d5da51e bug removed
|\
| * 3096570 index on master: 89f11dd
|/
* 89f11dd (HEAD, master)
```

`git log --graph --decorate --oneline` output:

```
*   4aa0f82 (HEAD)
|\
| * bb34a5b index on HEAD: d5da51e
|/
*   d5da51e
|\
| * 3096570 index on master: 89f11dd
|/
* 89f11dd (master)
```

Comment: Oh sorry. Here it is. To be clear, I want 100% of stash 4aa0f82 on my master branch

Comment: You've got a stash commit checked out.  Very, very likely not what you want.  Try to make sense of the commit descriptions in your log output here, any effort you put into the attempt will be quite gratifyingly well repaid.

Comment: I want to turn the stash commit into a regular commit on my master branch. how do I do it? the stash descriptions do not help. when I do stash apply, it does not apply all the changes

Comment: could I push the stashed commit and pull it onto master, perhaps?

Comment: ok, I replaced the first log with what you have said. I will try to commit rather than stash next time, but what do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`4aa0f82` isn't a stash commit, or not anymore it isn't, anyway.  It looks like you've been doing your work on checked-out stash commits, regardless, the easiest way to get where you want from here, if I understand this correctly, is going to be

```
# if you want all the changes from master through 4aa0f82 (i.e. also the d5da51e work)
git checkout master
git merge --squash 4aa0f82   # HEAD@{1}, "where HEAD was 1 checkout ago" works too

# if you want just the 4aa0f82 changes, not the d5da51e ones:
git checkout master
git cherry-pick --no-commit 4aa0f82   # edit: might need `bb34a5b` here instead
git commit
```

but I'm pretty sure it's the first set you want, with the `d5da51e` changes.

Comment: Ok, I  resolved the issue by copying the content of every single file in the conflict from another eclipse instance before you replied, but thanks for the reply